# Editor Fields are not updating

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

I want to use the Editor Framework of GWT within my project.

In my View(which implements Editor) I have my UiBinder Field:

```
@UiField
TextBox text;
```

In my Presenter I inject via GIN the driver instance:

```
@Inject
public AppointmentPopupPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, final AppointmentDriver appointmentDriver)
```

When the presenter is called I try to initialize the driver with:

```
this.appointmentDriver.initialize(getView());
this.appointmentDriver.edit(new Appointment());
```

GINModule:

```
 bind(SimpleBeanEditorDriver.class).to(AppointmentDriver.class);
```

AppointmentDriver interface:

```
public interface AppointmentDriver extends SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Appointment, AppointmentPopupPresenter.MyView>{
```

}

Later when I listen to a button event I call:

```
appointmentDriver.flush();
```

but all properties are null and no error msg is thrown. If I look into the debugger into the textbox widget the instance of "editor" is null as well. dont know the internas but maybe this is a hint for you.

Appointment POJO(of course with void setText(String text)/String getText()):

```
 String text;
```

At the moment I am completely stuck so any help is more than welcome.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you do a `getView()` , does it return the same view as the one passed to the constructor and the same as shown in the ui? It could be the driver is initialized with a different view than the one actual shown and thus you will get the data from the incorrect view. I also don't understand why you do the bind, it seems unnecessary?

Comment: Yes I looked at the debugger and its the correct view. if i
change now my driver to the explict view instead of the view
interface:

public interface AppointmentDriver extends
SimpleBeanEditorDriver<Appointment, AppointmentPopupView>{}

and driver.initialize((AppointmentPopupView)getView());

its working. I really dont know why and I am feeling a little bit
unconfortable with the cast in my presenter. Why is the bind unnecessary, i thought i need it later to inject it?

Comment: I think I know what it is. Your driver should extend with `AppointmentPopupView` argument and not `MyView`. Because based on these arguments GWT generates driver code also your `AppointmentPopupView` should implement `Editor` because due to the way GWT works it needs the interface on each class that contains editor code otherwise it can't see the TextBox in te AppointmentPopupView.

Comment: Regarding the bind. I'm not to familiar with GIN, but as you use it, it looks to me it means that when `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` is used as argument the `AppointmentDriver` is injected. But in your code you use the `AppointmentDriver` directly and not the `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` so GIN inject doesn't `AppointmentDriver` instead and so no bind to is needed.

Comment: Hilbrand, thanks for your answer. This was excactly the issue. Regarding gin your are also right as it makes no sense at all to bind it with gin...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I assume the problem is, that you're just calling  `SimpleBeanEditorDriver.initialize(E editor)`. As far as I remember, you need to call `RequestFactoryEditorDriver.initialize(EventBus, RequestFactory, E)`

Maybe my little (now updated for GWT 2.3, but still completely unpolished) [example project](http://www.mediafire.com/file/u1yffwuxi441dip/playGwtEditors-03.zip) can help you.

Here's the snippet where I make the initialize calls:

```
    final MyRequestFactory requestFactory = GWT
            .create(MyRequestFactory.class);
    requestFactory.initialize(eventBus);

    final MyEditor myEditor = new MyEditor();
    driver.initialize(eventBus, requestFactory, myEditor);
```

It should be possible to refactor the project to use GIN.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sadly I am not using the RequestFactory as I am building up my on json/rest service so I only need the editor stuff. Anyway I will have a look on your project!